# DatePickerDialog arrow button stucks and behaves abnormally for language RTL

Tags: android, datepicker

While using `DatePickerDialog` for a language RTL(Arabic or Urdu) its swipe action works fine but the right and left arrow buttons show abnormal behavior. The right arrow stucks on the second click and in this scenario when the left button is clicked it takes to the starting point in the range (starting month in the range).

```
if (dpd == null) {
    dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
            WeatherBaseAdvisory.this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
} else {
    dpd.initialize(
            WeatherBaseAdvisory.this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
}
```

[image]